# SQL how to use values in a query for another query

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a list of dates which I can generate using:

```
SELECT date from 
    generate_series(
      '2016-05-09'::date,
      CURRENT_DATE,
      '1 day'::interval
    ) date
```

I want to perform another query on a table using each value in the above list:
An example of what I want to achieve for one of the date value:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table,
WHERE table.datecolumn > date
```

How do I perform the second query for all the values in the first query to get final output somewhat in the form:

```
datecol      count
2016-07-09   100
2016-07-10   200
2016-07-11   100
```

Comment: Have you tried SELECT COUNT(*),datecolumn FROM table,
WHERE table.datecolumn > date ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `LATERAL` join. See [7.2.1.5. LATERAL Subqueries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html) in Postgres docs.

```
SELECT
    dates.dt, Counts.c
FROM
    generate_series(
        '2016-05-09'::date,
        CURRENT_DATE,
        '1 day'::interval
    ) AS dates(dt)
    INNER JOIN LATERAL
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS c
        FROM table
        WHERE table.datecolumn > dates.dt
    ) AS Counts ON true
```